# How to enable zooming with two fingers in ngx-pinch-zoom

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

How to enable zooming with two fingers in ngx-pinch-zoom. Only double tap is working for zooming now. I'm using Ionic 5.0.0 app

```html
        <pinch-zoom [double-tap-scale]="5" >
           <img class="img" [src]="imagePath" alt="image" />
        </pinch-zoom>
```

Comment: have you installed library? `npm i ngx-pinch-zoom` . also tell if you are getting any error?

Comment: Double tap is working

Comment: But i need to zoom the image with two fingers instead of double tap.

Comment: Check the Properties: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pinch-zoom#properties. may be disabling double tap work for you. `double-tap="fasle"`

Answer (score 3):

The below code worked.

```html
        <pinch-zoom [limit-zoom]="4" >
           <img class="img" [src]="imagePath" alt="image" />
        </pinch-zoom>
```